# can't able to mutate the state value in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { config } from '../../config';
import axios from 'axios'

const initialState = {
    VideoData:'empty'
}

const VideoSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'VideoSlice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        fetchData: async(state)=>{
            // console.log(config.url)
            let Data = await axios.get(`${config.url}/v1/videos`)
            // console.log(Data);
            state.VideoData = Data;
        }
    }

})


// console.log(initialState.VideoData)
export const { fetchData }  = VideoSlice.actions;
export default VideoSlice.reducer
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question seems to be missing a question. Please describe the problem you have in more than just the title. Also, your code does not do anything besides create the action and the reducer; how are you using this, and how are you testing if the data is mutated?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.